# What circuit can use a falling edge to trigger this damped oscillating impulse waveform?

Tags: inductor, passive-networks, waveform, ringing

What circuit can generate the waveform shown below upon receiving a falling edge trigger?

The closest I've gotten is that it looks like an RLC that got charged then the loop got closed.  I'm guessing maybe I can use a transistor to close such a circuit, but honestly analog is really not my strong suit.  I'd like to be able to alter the amplitude, decay time, and oscillation frequency, so please provide formulae.

For what it's worth though, the divisions on the oscilloscope are 5V and 0.1ms.  An interesting twist on this is that it is powered by a 9V battery, but somehow the peak voltage is ~20V (it's not necessarily "double", it could be an arbitrary voltage).  So, somehow the impulse must be able to have a higher amplitude than the power that drives it.

I should also add that the triggers come more than once, sometimes milliseconds apart.  A delay to causing the pulse is fine as long as each trigger causes a pulse.

If you can recommend specific components (or types of components, e.g. ceramic vs electrolytic capacitors) I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

[image: The impulse I'd like to replicate]

Comment: How much delay time are you allowed from the trigger input until the start of your exponentially decaying burst?  Do you know within a reasonably short time (seconds, maybe minutes tops) that the trigger is about to come so that you can "arm" the system?

Comment: A short (<0.5ms) delay is fine.  This pulse needs to happen repeatedly, as the triggers come in at roughly 350Hz.  (I just realized I wrote the divisions were 1ms and not 0.1ms above. Fixing now.)

Answer (score 3):

Since you say up to 500 µs delay from the trigger edge to your exponentially decaying ringing signal is acceptable, here is a solution:

[image]

When the input trigger comes along, you have something close the switch for 500 µs.  This could be a microcontroller or a dedicated timing circuit like a one-shot.  During that time, current builds up in the inductor.

When the switch opens, the inductor current will get dumped onto C1, causing its voltage to rise.  L1 and C1 are a resonant circuit that continually slosh the energy originally in the inductor back and forth between each other, generating a sine voltage on C1.  R1 dampens these oscillations.  Instead of a endless sine, which would be the result of theoretical ideal L1 and C1, you get a sine with a decaying amplitude envelope as shown in by your scope trace.  The product of L1 and C1 set the frequency.  Once you have that you can select R1 to get the desired damping.

In practise, the switch is probably best implemented by a N channel FET, but could also be a NPN transistor.

Comment: In theory the current in L1 grows linearly with the time the circuit is closed. In practice is this also the case? Are there any real world barriers to this?

Comment: Also, in the steady state with the circuit open, this converges to 9V, not 0. Is there a way to design this to converge to 0?

Comment: @ldga: The current will rise linearly in L1 at first, but will level off due to its series resistance.  As for converging on 9 V, that's a good point that slipped past me.  You could capacitively couple the output.  Otherwise, a different topology altogether would be better.

Comment: Thanks Olin. After a few running starts, I managed to get this to work by moving the inductor down in the series and using the voltage across it as the output. When I get it all working, I'll post my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: this doesn't fully your question, but hopefully provides a small steer toward the most basic (and awful) approach.

This is exactly how my first [kart timing transponders](http://edeca.net/wp/electronics/kart-timing-mk1/) worked.  I really don't recommend that approach for anything in a real circuit, it's horrible!

The "sending" device looked like the below and was basically an inductor that got charged slowly (through a resistor) and was then effectively shorted to ground using a FET.  When fully on the FET effectively acts as a very small resistance (check Rds(on) for typical parts).

The schematic looks like:

[image]

IC1 is a PIC uC that controls the circuit.  C1 is large and stops the power supply dropping too low which caused the uC to reset.  C2 is small and was intended to filter out some noise.  This circuit was reverse engineered from elsewhere when I had even less knowledge than the small amount I now possess.

And the final board, so you can see coil size, looks like:

[image]

This created the rather nasty waveform shown below.  This was measured with the GND clip of the probe connected to the tip, effectively as a receive "antenna".

[image]

I forget the exact voltage scale from that scope trace but the circuit was powered by a 9V battery and I think the first few spikes were over 20V.

Comment: That's pretty cool.  Three questions: 1. Why do you have two capacitors in parallel to ground? Couldn't I use just one, or am I missing something? 2. I'm not very knowledgeable on transistors... can FETs act as a short and allow alternating current through them? 3. Where are you measuring this voltage? Across the inductor? Thanks!!

Comment: It's probably not cool, perhaps don't do this!  Answer updated for the other parts.